Identity of a story anthology containing "Murders in the Rue Morgue" and "The Great Stone Face"
I think I remember two specific books which I read in the summer of 1962.
One was The Wonderful Wizard of Oz one of several borrowed from the Cape May, New Jersey public library that summer. And the other was an anthology of short stories, possibly restricted to stories by American authors.   It was one of dozens of books which were in our summer house at Cape May when my parent bought it in 1958, and most of them were decades old in 1958.
If my memory is correct it would have been a regular sized hardcover book with a light colored surface.
I think that one story in it was about a French Canadian, possibly named Jean, who was building a sail boat to sail away from Canada, to escape from British rule.  The protagonist was described as boy, but I thought that was probably just an older writer referring to a young man in his 20s as a boy, since his behavior seemed adult to me.
And I think that book was where I read "The Great Stone Face" (1850) by Nathaniel Hawthorne.
And I remember that book for "The Murders in the Rue Morgue" (1841) by Edgar Allan Poe.

Poe's "The Murders in the Rue Morgue" and Hawthorne's "The Great Stone Face" are both in Volume 1 of the 5-volume anthology Short Story Classics (American) edited by William Patten. Published in 1905, it would have been "decades old in 1958." The full text is available from the Hathi Trust Digital Library.
The other story you remember might be "Jean Michaud's Little Ship" by Charles G. D. Roberts, in Volume 5 of the same anthology, which is indeed about a young French Canadian named Jean who builds a boat to escape British rule:

Mich' Masson—whose home, which served him best as a place to stay away from, was in the village of Grand Pré, far up on the Basin of Minas—had been Jean's close friend since early boyhood, in the days before Port Royal town had been captured by the English and found its name changed to Annapolis. He was a daring adventurer, hunter, woods-ranger, an implacable partisan of the French cause, and just now interested in the traffic between Acadie and the new French fortress city of Louisburg—a traffic which the English Governor was angrily determined to break up. Mich' Masson could sail a ship as well as set a dead-fall or lay an ambush. He had kept bright in Jean's heart the flame of hatred against the English conquerors of Acadie. It was he who had come to the aid of Jean's shipbuilding from time to time, when timbers had to be put in place which were too heavy for one pair of hands to work with. It was, indeed, at his suggestion that Jean had finally decided to sell his cottage on the outskirts of Annapolis town, his scrap of upland with its apple trees in full bearing, his strip of rich dikeland by the riverside—secretly to build his little ship for the forbidden traffic—and to settle under the walls of Louisburg, where the flag he loved should always wave over his roof-tree. It was Mich' Masson who had shown Jean how by this course he could quickly grow rich, and make a home for Barbe which that somewhat disconcerting and incomprehensible maiden would not scorn to accept. Mich' Masson loved his own honor. He loved Jean. He hated the English. Jean's secret was safe with him.


This should probably be the book I remember.   The table of contents lists many stories which are unfamiliar to me, but I could have forgotten them after 60 years.
